# MS Word Mail Merge - Suppress page if condition is met?

Tags: ms-word, conditional-statements, mailmerge

Is there a way to have MS Word suppress a full page IF a condition is met for a Mail Merge?

I.e.
  `{ IF { MERGEFIELD x } = "True" "insert text here" [SUPPRESS PAGE] }`

?

Perhaps there is another way to look at this if there is no straight forward answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only in the sense that "insert text here" can be a full page of text including paragraph marks and a page break. You have to avoid some things, e.g. Double quotation marks. Or it can be an  INCLUDETEXT field that inserts such a page. Then the "false" value needs to be absent or "".

Comment: @bibadia instead of the `insert text here` i really mean this: `{ IF { MERGEFIELD x } = "True" [SHOW PAGE] [SUPPRESS PAGE] }`. Is that possible?

Comment: No. The IF field only either inserts material A, or material B. Either material A or material B can be empty (""), but the field cannot suppress something that is inserted by another mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to wrap the conditional content in a section and then hide this section. There is some explanation about how to do it [here](http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/formattingdocument1/qt/Hiddentext.htm).

Another option is to use some toolkit based on OpenXML to show/hide conditional content. I have done this myself on several projects using Docentric toolkit, which is not free, but can be tailored to all kinds of possible scenarios, including yours. An example of conditional content is shown [here](http://www.docentric.com/documentation/examples/conditional-content).

I hope you will find something of the above useful.